# web3 in truffle.js file

Tags: web3js, truffle-migration

I am trying to deploy my contracts with the specific account the user is using instead of hard coding it. But in this code, I get an error as such:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'web3'
```

the truffle-config.js file is as follows:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
var acc;
web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        acc=account;
      }
    })

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      from: acc
    },
    develop: {
      port: 8545
    }
  }
};
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: did you install web3 package?. If not then install it with npm install web3

Comment: That is not the right way for deployment

Answer (score 1):

Try using `import` instead of require.
change this code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
```

to this code:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

Comment: tried this but showed the following error:                                                                                                SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
npm install web3
```

It installs web3 to your local dependencies. But I'm wondering what you are trying to achieve with that Web3 call in the first place?

Comment: In my application, the ethers shud be transferred from the user account only. But in truffle, the default will be account[0] only. I don't want that so trying to set up the from account using web3